# I was trying to implement insertionsort method byt i don't get a write array sorting

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, insertion-sort

My array is {8,3,5,9,2} and I get {3,5,9,2}

```
    public static void insertionsort(int[] a) {
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        int value = a[i];
        // int c=0;
        for (int j = i - 1; value < a[j + 1] && j >= 0; j--) {
            int temp = a[j - 1];
            a[j - 1] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
            // c++;
        }

    }
}
```

Could some one help me figure out the problem in my code

.

Comment: it seems the for loop you should start from 0 instead 1

Comment: it gets the same answer @NghiaDo

Comment: @NghiaDo insertion sort starts with already sorted 1 element subarray so 1 is correct here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never enter the second for loop.

At start `i=1 j=i-1 value=3 a[j+1]=3`
`value < a[j + 1]` is like `3<3` so it is always false.

Try this:

```
    int n = a.length; 
    for (int i=1; i<n; ++i) 
    { 
        int temp = a[i]; 
        int j = i-1; 

        while (j >= 0 && a[j] > temp) 
        { 
            a[j+1] = a[j]; 
            j = j-1; 
        } 
        a[j+1] = temp; 
    }
```

Comment: at the 
a[j+1]=temp; why don't I write a[ i-1]=temp; ?

Comment: If you print the values of i and j you will see that `j+1` and `i-1` doesn't give the same result at each step of the for loop. So a[j+1] works for this algorithm.

Comment: for further use how can I use a pre implemented  sorting techniques from a package , using this
 import java.util.Array.sort();

Comment: The Arrays class has a static method for sorting an integer array into ascending numerical order. It is in the java.util package. `import java.util.Arrays;` `Arrays.sort(a);`